# Выборка из БД по нескольким условиям

Tags: php, kohana, mysql

Нужно реализовать некий фильтр по товарам (например, с/без фото, с/без описания и т.д.). В случае, если параметр не задан, то ничего добавлять в запрос не нужно

```
public function action_index() 
{

$orm = '';

if(isset($_POST['filter_submit']))

{

    if(!empty($_POST['filter_name']))
        {
            $name = $_POST['filter_name'];
            $orm .= "->where('name', '=', $name)";
        }

        switch($_POST['filter_main_image'])
        {
            case 1:
                $orm .= "->where('main_image','!=','')"; 
                break;
            case 2:
                $orm .= "->where('main_image','=','')";
                break;             
        }

  // Как здесь прикрутить переменную $orm перед find_all()
        $products = ORM::factory('product')->find_all();              
    }

  $content = View::factory('admin/a_products/va_products_index')
     ->bind('products', $products);

    // Выводим в шаблон
    $this->template->page_title = 'Продукты';
    $this->template->block_center = array($content);
}
```

Готов выслушать любые другие варианты как это можно реализовать, потому как данный вариант - не торт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ORM::factory('product')
```

Возвращает объект, передайте его переменной сначала, потом, если необходимо, задайте условие where, после чего find_all().

как-то так:

```
$orm = ORM::factory('product');
switch ($value) {
    case '1':
        $orm->where('1','=','1');
    break;
}
$products = $orm->find_all();
```

Comment: а если будет много switch, не будет он ловить только последний?

Comment: Да сколько угодно

Comment: пробую твое решение

Comment: ПыСы. Советую читать код и документацию:)

class Kohana_ORM extends Model implements serializable

//Alias of and_where()
public function where($column, $op, $value)

Выше писали про класс Arr, хороший совет, почитай:
http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Arr

Comment: Твое решение работает) Спасибо. Кохану учу второй месяц. Многое еще не знаю)

Comment: Да я сам за 2 года так не разу не использовал не ORM не встроенный View. :)

Вместо View использую Smarty, вместо ORM - Query_Builder

Comment: Я наоборот ORM использую, вроде слышал, что он более ресурсоемок, но пока что высоконагруженные проекты не приходилось делать

Answer (score 1):

```
switch($_POST['filter_main_image'])
        {
            case 1:
                $orm .= "->where('main_image','!=','')"; 
                break;
            case 2:
                $orm .= "->where('main_image','=','')";
                break; 
            default: $orm .= ""; // типа ничего не выбрано
                break;

        }
```

и запросы принимай через класс Arr в самой кохане

Comment: А можешь немного подробнее, как через Arr